# Scipy: epsilon neighborhood by sparse similarity with threshold

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance, similarity

I am wondering if scipy offers the option to implement a primitive but memory-friendly approach to epsilon neighborhood search:

Compute pairwise similarity for my data, but set all similarities smaller than a threshold `epsilon` to zero on the fly and then output result directly as sparse matrix.

For example `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()` is really fast, but the memory limit is reached early compared to my time limit, at least if I take `squareform()`.

I know there are O(n*log(n)) solutions in this case but for now it would be enough if the result could be sparse. Also obviously I would have to use a similarity as opposed to a distance, but that should not be such a big problem, should it.

Comment: what is the similarity measure you want to use?  Depending on your choice, there are different options you can employ.

Comment: I have not decided yet, probably in the end it will not be spatial distances. Therefore I am interested in a generic solution which has O(n^2) time complexity but at least saves some memory...

Comment: Another problem is that the scipy method does not allow to specify which pairs to compare. For example if I first compare all pairs in AxA and all pairs in BxB, and then later I want to merge the comparisons and add only AxB. This would be simply solved if I could pass two datasets A,B to the function (default A=B)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can recast your similarity measure in terms of a distance metric (say 1 minus the similarity) then the most efficient solution is to use sklearn's [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html).

Otherwise you could build a your own scipy.sparse.csr_matrix matrix by comparing each point against the other $ i -1$ points and throwing away all values smaller than the threshold.

Without knowing your specific similarity metric, this code should roughly do the trick:

```
import scipy.sparse as spsparse
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np


def sparse_similarity(X, epsilon=0.99, Y=None, similarity_metric=cosine_similarity):
    '''
    X : ndarray
        An m by n array of m original observations in an n-dimensional space.
    '''
    Nx, Dx = X.shape
    if Y is None:
        Y=X
    Ny, Dy = Y.shape

    assert Dx==Dy


    data = []
    indices = []
    indptr = [0]
    for ix in range(Nx):
        xsim = similarity_metric([X[ix]], Y)
        _ , kept_points = np.nonzero(xsim>=epsilon)
        data.extend(xsim[0,kept_points])
        indices.extend(kept_points)
        indptr.append(indptr[-1] + len(kept_points))

    return spsparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(Nx,Ny))


X = np.random.random(size=(1000,10))
sparse_similarity(X, epsilon=0.95)
```

Comment: I have scanned over the paper http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~taoyf/paper/sigmod15-dbscan.pdf which leaves me somewhat sceptical whether n^2 time complexity can be improved. But maybe the space complexity of the BallTree is at least lower. I will consider your input and do some more research on the matter.

Comment: Can you suggest an implementation for your second option. Because I tried some approach using itertools and element-wise comparison in python and it is ridiculously slow...

Comment: I've updated the answer to contain a rough code snippet, but, without knowing your specific similarity metric, its tough to optimize.  Also, the code with take two sets of points, but can be optimized further if you are only comparing within one set.  Hope that helps.